# Attaching a web cam on PC and connect it to KAA

Tags: camera, connection, external, kaa

I am new to KAA IOT platform. For testing purpose, I have attached a web cam to PC and want to connect this web cam to KAA server. Please tell how to achieve this task. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hello @Waleed I achieved it following way:-
>
> In order to connect to camera follow these steps:
>   UI Command->REST
>   Middle-ware-> KAA IoT->Notification->Camera Gateway-> Camera receive
>   the command

Comment: Thanks for your response.